# How can I open a meteor package in terminal and then work on it in Webstorm?

Tags: terminal, meteor, phpstorm, webstorm

If I've created a new meteor project (through adding packages) in terminal, how do I then actually SEE that project in  my editor, Webstorm?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it's really not clear what you are asking or what you did. Can't you just open the files meteor created in webstorm?

Comment: It was clear; it was just a very basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new Webstorm project from existing files:

1. Open Webstorm
2. Click `FILE`
3. Click `OPEN` with the folder icon next to it
4. Find and click the directory that contains your Meteor app and packages

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously open your meteor project in web storm. If you mean how do you open a package to read the code they are stored as sym links by webstorm and you can open them from .meteorite in your home directory, or where ever you have installed it of you want to dig into the meteorite package code